# Exclusão de tabelas relacionadas

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, jpa

Bom dia, estou tentando realizar a exclusão da minha classe usuário mas estou tendo o seguinte erro "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pitangdb`.`phone`, CONSTRAINT `FKss9h0qo6opj3b1hvh9k3x3o9j` FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`) REFERENCES `user` (`userId`))", teria alguma forma de resolver isso diretamente pelo JPA?

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 6, max = 50)
    private String password;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Column(name = "phones", nullable = false)
    private List<Phone> phones;











@Entity
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPhone;
    
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
    private User user;
    
    @Column
    private String number;
    
    @Column
    private String typePhone;
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu reproduzi o seu código e não tive problema.

Fiz o mapeamento conforme você fez acima.

User:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Column(name = "phones", nullable = false)
    private List<Phone> phones;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPhone;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
    private User user;
    
    @Column
    private String number;
    
    @Column
    private String typePhone;
}
```

Salvei as informações usando uma chamada em um controller:

```java
  @PostMapping(path="/add")
  public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
      , @RequestParam String email) {
    
    User n = new User();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setEmail(email);
    
    Phone p = new Phone();
    p.setUser(n);
    p.setNumber("10101010");
    
    userRepository.save(n);
    phoneRepository.save(p);
    return "Saved";
  }
```

Depois chamei esse delete e ele funciona apagando o usuario e telefone.

```java
  @GetMapping(path="/test-delete")
  public @ResponseBody String testDelete() {
      Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(2L);
      if (user.isPresent())
          userRepository.delete(user.get());
      return "Ok!";
  }
```

Comment: Queria entender quem sinalizou como uma resposta negativa, o que poderia ter sido feito de melhor na resposta, visto que busquei contribuir reproduzindo o código, não gerou erro e postei o mesmo aqui para demonstração.